# Conflict Jquery - Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a form made with multipage Gravity Form with Ajax enabled in Wordpress.

Since it is not possible to clone the fields that must have a unique ID, for me it is necessary to insert a field on each page that, if modified, sets the value equal to the other fields of the other pages.

The script works in multipage but not with the Ajax option enabled. Ajax is necessary for not completely reload the page but only the form because in the page I have third-party information in a iframe that does not need to be updated.

How can I resolve this conflict?

Thanks

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#input_3_4').on('change',function(){
           var info = jQuery('#input_3_4').val();
           alert(info);
           $('#input_3_6').val(info);
           $('#input_3_7').val(info);
         });
        jQuery('#input_3_6').on('change',function(){
           var info = jQuery('#input_3_6').val();
           alert(info);
           $('#input_3_4').val(info);
           $('#input_3_7').val(info);
         });
        jQuery('#input_3_7').on('change',function(){
           var info = jQuery('#input_3_7').val();
           alert(info);
           $('#input_3_4').val(info);
           $('#input_3_6').val(info);
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this can be simplified massively by using a class for all inputs.  But you ask about ajax, yet show no ajax request so it is difficult to know what your problem is

Comment: The solution is to use the jQuery hook gform_post_render https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_post_render/ to call the script for each page reload after ajax submission 

jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(){